# Formatting in Latex - Pseudocode

Tags: texmaker

I am trying to create a kind of pseudocode in Latex resembling the one shown below [image].

What I tried is:

1. Convert R to a binary region using the threshold $\theta_{0}$\
2. Assume N is the sum of the number of non-zero pixels within $F_{l}$ and $F_{r}$.\
3. If N is larger than a predefined threshold $\beta$, then\

   ```
       \begin{center}
       $\theta_{0} = \theta_{0} + \Delta\theta$\\
       Repeat the procedure from step 1
       \end{center}
   ```

   Else

   ```
       \begin{center}
       $\theta = \theta_{0}$
       \end{center}
   ```

   End

Its not turning out like I want though. Can anyone please suggest how to fix this?